# Experiences regarding single responsibility actions in vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am coming from a redux (with sagas) background and architecting a vuex project. I'm considering 2 different ways of setting up the actions, and looking for experiences and reasons why I might choose one over the other. For example, consider the action fetchPermissions();

In Option A, the actions might look like this:

```
export const fetchPermissions = async ({commit}) => {
     commit('setLoading', true);
     const response = await api.get('permission/permissions');
     if(response.data === success) {
         commit('setPermissions', response.data);
         commit('setLoading', false);
     }
     else {
         commit('setError', response.data);
         commit('setLoading', false);
     }
};
```

The above is useful because I can have one action that handles the entire flow for fetching permissions, and commits different state updates which are all independent. This works fine, however there seems to be a code smell, ie, fetchPermissions isn't responsible for setPermissions.

An alternative (also the redux way) would be to have single responsibility actions, Something more like:

```
export const fetchPermissions = async ({commit}) => {
     commit('setLoading', true);
     const response = await api.get('permission/permissions');
     if(response.data === success) {
         dispatch('fetchPermissionsSuccess', response.data);
     }
     else {
         dispatch('fetchPermissionsSuccessFailure', response.data);         
     }
};


export const fetchPermissionsSuccess = async ({commit}, data) => {
     commit('setPermissions', data);
     commit('setLoading', false);
};


export const fetchPermissionsFailure = async ({commit}, error) => {
     commit('setError', error);
     commit('setLoading', true);
};
```

I like option A because this would be easier for the team to follow and reduces the number of actions by 66% so alot less bulk.

I like the Single Responsibility Principle mindset of Option B. The other potential benefit of Option B is that I could create a service that listens for a list of bound actions, and does something based upon whether or not it sees one. For instance, you could have a service that submits a message each time any actionSuccess occurs, or actionFailure.

Is there a vuex best practice that addresses this, or what have you learned from experience is the way to go.

Comment: I don't think you're thinking in the `vuex` way - I'd suggest using modules and coupling all the logic for a modules state together, and creating an API class that handles all the ajax/endpoint related events to call out to in your actions. Of course, any state change *must* occur in your mutations

Comment: Hi Derek, I think that is what I have done. This is an example of the actions methods within the Permissions module under the root store, and api is a service that calls axios. The state changes occur only in the mutations(not shown as they are in a separate mutations file, but I do show the commits to them). If this isn't what you mean, please expand upon your answer.

Comment: This is an architectural question and likely to be highly opinionated.  I personally try to keep requests out of the store as much as possible, so another option would be to call the api outside of the store and then only have an action/mutation for setting the permissions.

Comment: Will the `fetchPermissionsSuccess` action be dispatched in more than one place? If not then option B is excessive. It's definitely not something I'd typically see in Vuex.

Comment: @StevenB. Can you give an example of how an externally called api would look?

Comment: @Chris I just mean to call the api when you need it from a component, possibly when they login, and then call the vuex action from that component.  So it's external to the store.